# aurelia app with AD b2c Hosted on Azure, redirects back to login on Edge and Firefox

Tags: firefox, aurelia, microsoft-edge, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have an Aurelia app that authenticates with Azure B2C using the Msal JavaScript library.
It is Hosted on an Azure app service, It works fine in Chrome but in Edge and Firefox i get redirected back to the Azure B2C login screen when the app starts.

This is my main.ts:

```
aurelia.start().then((a) => {
  let auth: Auth = a
    .container
    .get(Auth);

  setTimeout(() => {
    auth
      .isAuthenticated()
      .then(() => {
        a.setRoot();
        return;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        auth.login();
      });
  }, 2000);
```

This is the isAuthenticated method:

```
isAuthenticated() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let cachedUser = this
    .clientApplication
    .getUser();

  if (cachedUser == null) {
    this.authenticated = false;
    return reject();
  }

  let token = this._getTokentInternal();
  if (token) {
    this.authenticated = true;
    return resolve();
  } else {

    return reject();
  }
 });
}
```

This works fine when i run on Localhost with the Aurelia cli, all three browsers work, but when i publish to azure, Edge and Firefox keep getting a rejected promise response from the isAuthenticated method even though azure login was successful, this forces a redirect to login.
Has anyone else experienced this problem?
Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my login method cleared the window.location.hash, I removed that line and it seems to be working now